# Should I expose a server on OpenWrt to WAN or only to LAN with port-forwarding from WAN?

Tags: router, firewall, port-forwarding, openwrt

If I installed a server on a computer behind a router and wanted to allow connection to it from the Internet, I would have to do two things:  One, open the firewall on the server machine to allow the incoming connection; and two, set up a port forwarding rule on the router so the connection may go from WAN to LAN (specifically to the server machine).

But what should I do if the server machine in question is the router itself running on OpenWrt?

I can think of two options.

Option A.  Treat the router like any other computer in LAN.  After installing the server on the router, open the firewall to allow incoming connection from within LAN to the server.  (I believe this is done in LuCI > Network > Firewall > Traffic Rules.)  Then, set up a port forwarding rule from WAN to LAN (specifically the server). (LuCI > Network > Firewall > Port Forwards.)

Option B. Use LuCI's Traffic Rules tab to open the firewall for connection from WAN directly to the server.

The questions are:

1. Am I right to think these are the two options I may consider?
2. What would be the pros and cons on either side?
3. What is the standard practice?

The server in question may be a VPN server (e.g. Wireguard) or OpenSSH, which I may install in place of Dropbear.  But the same question would arise if you  installed an A/V stream server on OpenWrt (assuming that's possible).  In other words, I want this question to remain a generic one on the two options above rather than be limited to any particular software (Wireguard etc.).

I am new to both OpenWrt and Linux. I didn't know OpenWrt existed until just a few days ago.  It is possible that option A is bonkers (something no one ever does) and that my brain only thought it up because it never saw anything like OpenWrt before and can only think in "regular router" terms.

Actually, that makes me think Option A may have this advantage going for it.  I have actually done port forwarding before, but Linux firewall is new to me. So I might mass up on Traffic Rules, and it would be better if the mess-up happens only in LAN.

Please advise. Thanks.

ADDENDUM

These are LuCI screenshots illustrating Option A (left) and B (right).  The left panel assumes that port 12000 has been opened to LAN (either by default policy or specific traffic rule).   192.168.1.1. is the router's LAN IP address.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*(While not apparent on some browsers, each file path is a link)*</sup>

For SSH, standard practice is to specify a [DNAT](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/fw3_nat) rule [port forward] to the internal network it resides within; whereas for the VPN server, you'd create a rule to allow WAN access to its server port:

- **[Wireguard Wiki](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/wireguard/server)**
- **[SSH](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-quick-start/sshadministration):**

  - **[`/etc/config/firewall`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/firewall_configuration):**

    ```bsh
    #

        ##::[[---  OpenWrt WAN Firewall Config  ---]]::##

    #===========================================================
                  ##----- NAT Redirects -----##
    #===========================================================

    # SSH #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    config redirect
        option  target          'DNAT'
        option  proto           'tcp'
        option  src             'wan'
        option  src_dport       60501
        option  dest            'lan'
        option  dest_ip         192.168.1.1
        option  dest_port       22
        option  name            'Allow Redirect WAN → LAN (SSH)'

    config redirect
        option  target          'DNAT'
        option  proto           'tcp'
        option  src             'vpn'
        option  src_dport       60502
        option  dest            'lan'
        option  dest_ip         192.168.1.1
        option  dest_port       22
        option  name            'Allow Redirect Wireguard → LAN (SSH)'

    #===========================================================
                      ##----- VPN Zones -----##
    #===========================================================

    # Wireguard #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    config zone
        option  name            'vpn'
        option  network         'vpn'
        option  input           'ACCEPT'
        option  forward         'ACCEPT'
        option  output          'ACCEPT'
        option  log             1

    # Rules:
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    config rule
        option  target          'ACCEPT'
        option  proto           'tcp udp'
        option  src             'wan'
        option  dest            '*'
        option  dest_port       51820
        option  name            'Allow Forwarded Wireguard → Router'

    config rule
        option  target          'ACCEPT'
        option  proto           'tcp'
        option  src             'vpn'
        option  dest            '*'
        option  dest_port       60502
        option  name            'Allow Wireguard → Router (SSH)'
    ```
  - **[`/etc/config/dropbear`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dropbear):**

    ```ini
    #

          ##::[[---  OpenWrt DropBear Config  ---]]::##

    #===========================================================
                     ##----- Default -----##
    #===========================================================

    # Server #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    config dropbear
        option  enable            1
        option  Interface         'lan'
        option  PasswordAuth      'off'
        option  RootPasswordAuth  'off'
        option  IdleTimeout       0
        option  Port              22
        option  RootLogin         1
        option  SSHKeepAlive      300
        option  verbose           1
    ```
  - **[`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/BSD-Linux/sshd_config):** <sup>([Customized](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH))</sup>

    ```ini
    #

        ##::[[---  OpenWrt OpenSSH SSHd Config  ---]]::##

    #===========================================================
                  ##----- Global Options -----##
    #===========================================================

      # Please verify, as all algorithms may not supported:

        # Ciphers:                  # HostKey & KeyTypes
          ## ssh -Q cipher            ## ssh -Q key

        # Kex [Key Exchange]        # MAC [Message Authentication Code]
          ## ssh -Q kex               ## ssh -Q mac


    # Connection #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    AddressFamily                     = inet
    ListenAddress                     = 192.168.1.1:22


    # Encryption #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    AuthorizedKeysFile                = /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

    HostKey                           = /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
    HostKey                           = /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key


    # Authentication #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    AllowUsers                        = root
    AllowGroups                       = root

    ChallengeResponseAuthentication   = no
    PasswordAuthentication            = no
    PermitEmptyPasswords              = no

    StrictModes                       = yes
    PubkeyAuthentication              = yes

    LoginGraceTime                    = 30

    MaxAuthTries                      = 3
    MaxSessions                       = 10
    MaxStartups                       = 3:30:10

    PermitRootLogin                   = prohibit-password


    # Reliability #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    ClientAliveCountMax               = 3
    ClientAliveInterval               = 600

    TCPKeepAlive                      = yes

    UseDNS                            = yes


    # Security #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    AllowAgentForwarding              = yes
    AllowTcpForwarding                = yes

    GatewayPorts                      = clientspecified
    PermitTunnel                      = yes

    Subsystem   sftp                  = /usr/lib/sftp-server

    RekeyLimit                        = 500M 60m


    # Logging #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    SyslogFacility                    = AUTH
    LogLevel                          = VERBOSE

    PidFile                           = /tmp/run/sshd.pid


    # Ciphers and ReKeying #
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    FingerprintHash                   = sha256

    Ciphers                           = aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

    HostKeyAlgorithms                 = ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521

    HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes         = ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521

    KexAlgorithms                     = curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve25519-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

    MACs                              = hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512

    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes            = ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    ```
- **[LuCI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/luci/luci.secure):**

  1. **`https://<router IP>`** → ***Network*** <sup>*(left-hand menu)*</sup> → ***Firewall***
  2. ***Traffic Rules***

     1. **ADD:** 
         *Name:* `Allow Forwarded Wireguard → Router` 
         *Protocol:* `TCP UDP` 
         *Source Zone:* `wan` 
         *Destination Zone:* `Any zone (forward)` 
         *Destination Port:* `51820` 
         *Action:* `accept` 
         **SAVE**
     2. **ADD:** 
         *Name:* `Allow Wireguard → Router (SSH)` 
         *Protocol:* `TCP` 
         *Source Zone:* `vpn` 
         *Destination Zone:* `Any zone (forward)` 
         *Destination Port:* `60502` 
         *Action:* `accept` 
         **SAVE**
  3. ***[Port Forwards](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/luci/port_forwards)***

     1. **ADD:** 
         *Name:* `Allow Redirect WAN → LAN (SSH)` 
         *Protocol:* `TCP` 
         *Source Zone:* `wan` 
         *External Port:* `60501` 
         *Destination Zone:* `lan` 
         *Internal IP address:* `192.168.1.1` 
         *Internal Port:* `22` 
         *Action:* `accept` 
         **SAVE**
     2. **ADD:** 
         *Name:* `Allow Redirect VPN → LAN (SSH)` 
         *Protocol:* `TCP` 
         *Source Zone:* `vpn` 
         *External Port:* `60502` 
         *Destination Zone:* `lan` 
         *Internal IP address:* `192.168.1.1` 
         *Internal Port:* `22` 
         *Action:* `accept` 
         **SAVE**
  4. **SAVE & APPLY**

Comment: @Catomic The content isn't advanced, it's just in a format you're not familiar with, as it comes from the config files you access via SSH, a more efficient means of presenting the info than via the steps required in LuCI [the WebAdmin]. **(1)** Yes, DNAT [Destination NAT] is port forwarding; **(2)** The Wireguard server port is accessible from WAN, but Wireguard itself is not directly exposed to WAN due to the stateful firewall [[`fw3`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/start)]. I didn't articulate the first part of the answer quite right and have edited it.

Comment: @Catomic I don't have time at the moment, but within the next few days I'll incorporate the LuCI steps into the answer

Comment: Thanks! The additional bit in the answer and the comments are very helpful as they tell me how I should interpret the unfamiliar code.   Somehow I cannot add the @JW0914 flag.

Comment: @Catomic _(With only the author and a single commenter, author mentions aren't necessary, so they're not allowed)_ I've updated with the LuCI steps.